# Flutter: null locale.countryCode on iOS

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

This is what I use for Android and iOS

```
final List<Locale> systemLocales = WidgetsBinding.instance!.window.locales;
String countryCode = WidgetsBinding.instance!.window.locale.countryCode;
```

On Android it works fine:

[image]

But on iOS the country code comes null:

[image]

Comment: Have you ran it on a physical iOS device? Or just the Simulator? The Simulator is quite limited. If I run the same code on my Simulator, I get null but then I get a country code when I run it on my iPhone.

Comment: I was trying on a simulator but even if it doesn't work there I'd need something to test it. I'll put the solution I found

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solution just for iOS if we cannot get the country code:

```
Future<String> _getCountryCode() async {
    final link = Uri.parse('http://ip-api.com/json');
    final jsonEncoded = await http.read(link);
    final Map jsonDecoded = json.decode(jsonEncoded);

    return jsonDecoded['countryCode'];
  }
```

Comment: It is not really an answer to reach out for external HTTP call / 3rd party service for something built in.

Comment: share your answer. If it's better I'll accept it instead